# PHP Simple HTML Dom - tag attrib

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

i'm trying try grab the plain text from within `<font size="3" color="blue">` ... its not picking up the font tag, although it does work if I do **"font", 3** but there are a lot of font tags in the site and i'd like to make the search a bit more specific. is it possible to have multiple attribs on a tag?

```
<?php

include('simple_html_dom.php');

$html = new simple_html_dom();   
$html = file_get_html('http://cwheel.domain.com/');

##### <font size="3" color="blue">Certified Genuine</font>
$element = $html->find("font[size=3][color=blue]", 0);  
echo $element-> plaintext . '<br>';
$html->clear();

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know Simple_html_dom. But it seems the query you are trying to pass is an xpath query. In that case you need to use prefix attributes with `@`. Also you need to prefix the whole query with `//` to make sure it searches for any `font` tag that is in any level deep. Final query should look something like this.

`//font[@size=3][@color=blue]`

Using DOMDocument and DOMXPath [it works pretty good](http://3v4l.org/mJrfr).

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$fonts = $xpath->query('font[@size="3" ][ @color="blue"]');
foreach($fonts as $font){
    echo $font->textContent. "\n";
}
```